# Updating to the latest CakePHP 3.0 changes through Composer

Tags: composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I have installed CakePHP 3.0 using Composer on my PC (Ubuntu). I want to update the changes of CakePHP 3.0.

I have used the following link provided at [CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#keeping-up-to-date-with-the-latest-cakephp-changes) after changing the required package, but I am getting the below error in the terminal:

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ php composer.phar update    Composer could not find a
>   composer.json file in /home/ubuntu To initialize a project, please
>   create a composer.json file as described in the
>   http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Could you please provide a proper suggestion?

Note: I have the composer.json file in the project directory, so what should I do in that case?

Comment: where are your cake files? Are they in /home/ubuntu/public_html/xyz or somewhere else?

Comment: @rrd, My cake file is at /var/www/html/cake_project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should issue that command in the project directory, where composer.phar and composer.json should be present. So `cd /var/www/html/cake_project` first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i copied composer.phar to the project directory then execute the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment path to use composer in command line or you only need copy file composer.phar into your project folder and then cd into you project folder.
Finally, you run command `php composer.phar update`
Composer that will auto update CakePHP latest version.

http://rao5s.vn

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion. It's already solved a year ago